# Display a reminder of Meta's scope when first question is asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There have been cases from time to time when new users post programming questions on Meta SO. As a new user myself once, it is often the case that the only thing that matters is the question itself, and there is no real perception or importance given to rep. So not much attention is paid to the FAQs unless pointed out in the comments. But this is often followed by heavy downvoting and the question being closed. Hence a preventive suggestion would be to have a message that questions in Meta are about SO itself and programming related questions should go to SO. This should be only there when a user posts his first question.

This might prevent cases where people ask questions in Meta SO, it gets closed as off-topic and it never gets posted on SO sometimes happens to good questions as well.

There might still be a case when people do not read the message, but it might help in decreasing the number of times this happens, while saving the new user from downvotes and a cold reception.

I remember that before coming into the SO community I had already been reading a lot of questions and had already a good idea which questions go where, but not everyone might be the same way.

Thanks.

Comment: The Help Center for each site contains the information that the users need to ask a good question. I am not sure that we are helping users by enabling ignorance by providing thumbnail versions of the site guidelines for beginners. Heavy downvotes are one way to tell a user to take a step back and figure out what they did wrong.

Comment: I thought that the unavailable language tags are a huge tip in themselves.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins But a disclaimer might open the eyes of a relatively well-meaning new user. I understand that the Help Center is right. But given that (apparently) well-meaning new users still seem to be doing this, maybe a preventive measure such as this would only help, rather than deterorate the quality of content on the site, in a less discouraging way. I'm not that sure about it hence it is in discussion :) please do give your inputs

Comment: Those who don't read [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z07Y0.png) won't read any disclaimer as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm jaded, but I think that a user who doesn't read the documentation is not necessarily an asset to the site, and the discouragement that comes as a result of doing it wrong may be exactly what is needed. The goal is to create good questions and answers: teaching individual users _how_ to do that (when the help documentation already does it) distracts from the bigger picture.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I actually missed seeing that !! Maybe the fact that it was in the right corner was the reason. But I agree that someone who doesn't read that might miss the disclaimer as well. My real reason for asking is the fact that such posts are so common that maybe a big bold "hard to miss" disclaimer would only help, rather than hinder the user's awareness, especially since he is new to the site. but I could be totally wrong here

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - I agree with that. But I feel not everyone reacts to discouragement the same way. Some people (such as myself) would go above and beyond to improve when told the right thing to do in a direct(A disclaimer before posting) rather than an indirect (understand that there are 100 downvotes, hence I should not have done that) way :). But that is just opinion-related. What do you perceive as the reason that it would DECREASE the quality of the site, because I feel if anything, it would only help ?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Unless you do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqF8.png)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I feel the opposite, a manual (or help page) is a nessissary evil. Each time the end user must refer to it is a **big** negative score for the product. That said most people posting programing questions to meta are trying to get around a question ban

Comment: @hjpotter92: Problem is not all of them are unavailable.

Comment: We already do this for new users on Stack Overflow. Does that not exist for Meta? I don't want to open up a new account just for testing purposes..

Comment: @CodyGray please do let us know of your findings. :)

Comment: @RichardTingle but to think that posting a programming question in meta would get around a ban implies that the user is new to the site to think that meta is another platform for posting programming questions OR the user is just trying his luck anyways. Both cases, a disclaimer would be useful I hope. But please do give your input if you believe otherwise. :)

Comment: @sai I agree this is a good idea, but I don't think it'll 100% solve the problem (but 50% solved is better than none at all)

Comment: @RichardTingle Well said. :) thanks